# Tesseract decoding result is different for 64bit Windows OS and 32bit Ubuntu Linux OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ocr, tesseract

I am testing the same image attached to decode the number using `tesseract`. I tested in 64bit Windows OS and 32bit Ubuntu OS. The test result in Windows OS gives me a correct result. The Windows result is 43750, but 32bit Ubuntu gives me 43730. 
I use the same code as shown below

```
        tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;
        tess.Init("/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/", "eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
        tess.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
        tess.SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);
        //tess.SetImage((uchar*)extText.data, extText.cols, extText.rows, 1, extText.cols);
        // Get the text
        //readtxt = tess.GetUTF8Text();//GetUTF8Text();
        const char* image = "image.jpg";
        FILE *fin = fopen("image.jpg", "rb");
        if(fin == NULL){
            return FILE_ERROR;
        }
        fclose(fin);
        STRING text_out;
        if(!tess.ProcessPages(image, NULL, 0, &text_out)){
            return PROCESS_ERROR;
        }
        readtxt = text_out.string();
        return SUCCESS;
```

I installed in Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr tesseract-ocr-eng libtesseract-dev libleptonica-dev` command.

For the Windows PC, everything I build from all source codes, the version is Tesseract-3.02.

I replaced the tessdata folder from Windows PC and put it into /usr/share/tesseract-ocr. But the results are still different.

The only thing I can think of is 64bit and 32bit diffrence. Windows PC process in 64bit OS and Linux OS process in 32bit OS (Linux system processor is 64bit, but I install 32bit Ubuntu OS). Is that correct, because of 64bit and 32bit difference, the results are different?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: The result depends mainly on the version of Tesseract (Ubuntu 14.04 ships Tesseract 3.03), version of Leptonica, language data set, and rounding used in floating point operations by a given compiler. What version of Tesseract do you use on Linux?

Comment: @KarolS  Linux has 3.0.3 and Windows has 3.0.2. So in terms of lib version, Linux has higher version. So I can figure out only 64bit and 32bit problem. To make sure is I change the 32bit system to 64bit and test again. I can't do that right now as 32bit system is running for an application and can't stop it.

Comment: Newer version of Tesseract doesn't mean you will get better results. If you want to have more reproducible results, you need to have the same version. There is a lot of differences between 3.02 and 3.03.

Comment: Thanks, I know what I have to do. I wait for the system down and I'll test all those. I'll use same tesseract version for both and see the results. Can you answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason you get different results is that you use different version of Tesseract: 3.02 and 3.03. Despite seemingly minor version number difference, there are noticeable differences in recognition algorithms.

Here is the Tesseract changelog: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/ChangeLog

Also, the trained data are important. Training Tesseract yourself may help improve the results. I also had problems with 5's being misinterpreted as 3's, I partially solved it by training Tesseract for the font.